# java.util.date returns 502 from jtOpen ObjectDescription.RESTORE_DATE

Tags: java, python, jython, ibm-midrange, jtopen

I have the following in jython talking to an AS400:

```
system = AS400(ip, USER, PWORD)
obj = ObjectDescription(system, 'qsys','jbrdata', 'lib')
d = obj.RESTORE_DATE
```

The object that returns is a java.util.DATE/INT but unlike what i expected its only a 3 digit response. I need to get the date in a YYYYMMDD format

Can someone please help me with this?

I looked at the [documentation](https://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/index.html?com/ibm/as400/access/ObjectDescription.html) here but it doesn't seem helpful

Answer (score 0):

Since the `getValue(ObjectDescription.RESTORE_DATE)` method is returning a `Date` object, you'll need to format it as a date.

In Java you can do this using a `DateFormat` object.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ymd");
```